# Cast icon shows up only first time activity is loaded

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I'm using the Chromecast Companion Library and my chromecast icon is displayed the first time my activity is created. But then when I leave the activity and then go back to it, the cast icon won't show. Here's the relevant code for how I'm adding the chromecast icon and updating it's display:

In my layout XML:

```
<android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton
    android:id="@+id/media_route_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:mediaRouteTypes="user"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />
```

In my activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
mCastManager = RadioPup.getCastManager(this);
    mMediaRouteButton = (MediaRouteButton) findViewById(R.id.media_route_button);
    mCastManager.addMediaRouterButton(mMediaRouteButton);
    setupCastListener();
}

private void setupCastListener() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "SETUP CAST LISTENER");
    mCastConsumer = new VideoCastConsumerImpl() {
        @Override
        public void onCastAvailabilityChanged(boolean castPresent) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "CAST AVAILABILITY CHANGED");
             mMediaRouteButton.setVisibility(castPresent ? View.VISIBLE : 
            View.INVISIBLE);
            }

        @Override
        public void onApplicationConnected(ApplicationMetadata appMetadata,
                String sessionId, boolean wasLaunched) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "CAST APPLICATION CONNECTED");
        }

        @Override
        public void onApplicationDisconnected(int errorCode) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRemoteMediaPlayerMetadataUpdated() {
            try {
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // silent
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailed(int resourceId, int statusCode) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectivityRecovered() {
        }

    };
}

protected void onDestroy() {
...
if (null != mCastManager) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onDestroy()");
        mCastManager.clearContext(this);
        mCastConsumer = null;
    }
}

protected void onPause() {
...
mCastManager.decrementUiCounter();
    mCastManager.removeVideoCastConsumer(mCastConsumer);
}

protected void onResume() {
...
mCastManager = RadioPup.getCastManager(this);
    mCastManager.incrementUiCounter();
    mCastManager.addVideoCastConsumer(mCastConsumer);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have an issue where the cast availability event is being fired before any listeners are registered.  I never get the event again, so my app UI doesn't know to set the button to visible.  Did you ever have this issue? My code follows this pattern and the example code from CastVideos-android.  Also, I can background the app and foreground it, and then yes, I get the onCastDeviceConnected event and things are good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by also using this callback method:

```
        @Override
        public void onCastDeviceDetected(RouteInfo info) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "CAST DEVICE DETECTED");
            mMediaRouteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add `incrementUiCounter()` and `decrementUiCounter()` to you activities, please take a look at the CastVideos-android project for an example of that.

Comment: I don't use MediaRouteButton myself; can you provide a minimalistic project that exhibits the issue and post it on a Drive or DropBox so I can grab it and see where the issue is?